# Is Jesus seen as both the Passover Lamb and Goat(s) of the Atonement in any Protestant Theology?

Tags: protestantism, reformed-theology, christology, sacrifice, passover

It is often said that Jesus fulfilled the Jewish spring feasts when he first came and the expectation is that he will fulfill the fall feasts when we returns.

Also, that Jesus died at the time of Passover reinforces that he was at least understood as the perfect Passover Lamb.
See: [How does the Passover foreshadow the coming of Jesus as the Messiah?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6975/24841)

However, it seems to me Jesus also fulfilled at least part of the Day of Atonement (in the Fall season) where one goat dies and the other receives the sins of all the people(Is. 53:6) and then it is led out of the city, away from the people, removing their sins far away.

Many people will often [compare Christ to this scapegoat](http://www.thevillagechurch.net/sermon/the-gospel-in-the-day-of-atonement/) but I have yet to find any fuller treatment of how Yom Kippur was fulfilled in Christ's **first** earthly ministry rather than his second coming.

**Are there any Protestant/Reformed, or older, writings that deal with Jesus fulfilling the prophetic nature of Passover and Yom Kippur?**
Either affirming or denying, but specifically speaking to the concept of "fulfillment" of the two feasts in Jesus' first coming.

This may include catholic works, particularly from the early church, prior to the Reformation as well.

Comment: See http://www.waitingforjesus.com/jewishfeastsprophecy.html for one interpretation.

Comment: @Joshua You're asking if any Protestants see Jesus as the passover lamb or scapegoat, and the answer is obviously yes. Anyone with a basic level of knowledge on the topic would surely know that. They are both extremely common interpretations. The more interesting question would be if there were any sacrifices they didn't think were fulfilled in Christ.

Comment: "but I have yet to find any fuller treatment of how Yom Kippur was fulfilled in Christ's first earthly ministry rather than his second coming" This could be clearer - are you asking about strictly his pre-crucifixion ministry, or all of his ministry including his death and resurrection?

Comment: @curiousdannii I would include everything that was done in his first coming from conception to Ascension and even including the giving of the Holy Spirit at Pentecost. As suggested by my saying he fulfilled the spring feasts.

Comment: I'm still honestly confused about what the problem is with this question. It certainly had problems in its initial posting but my later edit had made it focused and specific in its request. Unfortunately a number of commenters have ignored the specific and intentional wording. The bolded question has not been addressed. If people are unfamiliar with something here I fail to understand how that is the question's fault. I don't understand many questions about JW theology. I do not assume it's because the questions are unclear, I assume it's because I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that every Christian denomination would see Jesus's death as the fulfilment of both the Passover sacrifice and the Day of Atonement sacrifices and rituals, because the identification is made in the scriptures themselves.

1 Corinthians 5:7 says directly that Christ is our Passover lamb:

> Cleanse out the old leaven that you may be a new lump, as you really are unleavened. For Christ, our Passover lamb, has been sacrificed.

Hebrews 9 is a lengthy comparison of the Jewish priests' ministry and Jesus' ministry. Its focus is more on showing that Jesus is the great high priest than explicitly saying he was the fulfilment of the goats, but the comparison is still there when it talks about his blood. The first paragraph shows that the Day of Atonement was the focus. The second shows the glorious truth that Jesus' death has done away with the need for all recurrent sacrifices!

> Hebrews 9:6-7: These preparations having thus been made, the priests go regularly into the first section, performing their ritual duties, but into the second only the high priest goes, and he but once a year, and not without taking blood, which he offers for himself and for the unintentional sins of the people.
>
> Hebrews 9:11-14: But when Christ appeared as a high priest of the good things that have come, then through the greater and more perfect tent (not made with hands, that is, not of this creation) he entered once for all into the holy places, not by means of the blood of goats and calves but **by means of his own blood**, thus securing an eternal redemption. For if the blood of goats and bulls, and the sprinkling of defiled persons with the ashes of a heifer, sanctify for the purification of the flesh, how much more will **the blood of Christ**, who through the eternal Spirit **offered himself without blemish to God**, purify our conscience from dead works to serve the living God.

Comment: I like the exclamation point (!) after the part about the sacrifices. I feel the same way. I'm writing this and my dog's head is on my shoulder. Unfortunately, they've already started work on a third temple and they're looking for Jewish men from the Levi tribe to start sacrificing animals. :o(

Comment: I've read it over a couple times, and it is a good answer. Unfortunately, my question isn't what it is answering. You make no mention of details of Yom Kippur that are mentioned in my 2nd and 3rd paragraphs. Also, the focus of my question has been changed from asking for reference to historic writings on this topic to you simply discussing the topic. Your answer is fine, but I'm not looking for your answer. I mean no offense by that, but this becomes a truth question as it is and I had hoped to avoid personal conjecture. Thanks for your effort on this, I hope it does help someone.

Comment: @Joshua I replied to you on chat about how the question could be better phrased. If you're after something specific then you really should edit it to clearly ask for that.